# how to embed Youtube videos in a Ionic 4 app

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular-dom-sanitizer

I am trying to develop an ionic app that i will be deploying as a pwa in which i want to embed Youtube Videos and display them in a grid. Video links, their titles, and brief descriptions are provided by my Cloud Firestore objects.

Now the problem is that when I am trying to use iframe in ionic app with single url like :

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6kqe2ICmTxc" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

then it is working but when I am binding it to my database Video URL, then it is not working. The console is showing that URL is not a safe url.

Now, I know that it can be fixed by using the DomSanitizer but i don't know how to use it for the array of objects that contains the required links.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this,

```
    trustedVideoUrl: SafeResourceUrl;
    array_of_objects = [{vid_link:"https://youtube.com/lalla"},{vid_link:"https://youtube.com/lalla"}]


    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
                private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

    ionViewWillEnter(): void {
      for(let i of array_of_objects){
        i.trustedVideoUrl = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(i.vid_link);
      }
    }
```

and in your HTML,

```
 <iframe *ngFor="let i of array_of_objects" width="100%" height="315" [src]="i.trustedVideoUrl" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

> There is one more thing we need to do in order to make this work on
>   iOS, we need to allow navigation to YouTube urls in our config.xml
>   file by adding the below line:

```
<allow-navigation href="https://*youtube.com/*"/>
```

Comment: It worked but only when I am navigating from a previous view to this page. When I refresh this page it throws an error saying **can't read property length of undefined at** 'for(let video of this.videos)'. Thanks in advance.

Comment: that means this.videos is an empty array when you are running this loop. Make sure that the data is fetched and filled in this.videos, before you run that loop

Comment: you have some bugs, for example `i.trustedVideoUrl` most be `this.trustedVideoUrl` be an array

Answer (score 0):

I will prefer to use freindly names and fix the bugs

```html
    <iframe
      *ngFor="let trustedLink of trustedVideoUrlArray"
      width="100%"
      height="315"
      [src]="trustedLink"
      frameborder="0"
      allowfullscreen
    ></iframe>
```

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SafeResourceUrl, DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-help',
  templateUrl: './help.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./help.page.scss'],
})
export class HelpPage implements OnInit {
  trustedVideoUrlArray: SafeResourceUrl[] = [];
  youtubeUrlsArray = [
    {
      link: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/ytLZo1RBS5U"
    },
    {
      link: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/ytLZo1RBS5U"
    }
  ]

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    for (let item of this.youtubeUrlsArray) {
      this.trustedVideoUrlArray.push(this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(item.link));
    }
  }

}
```